# Celery Redis reply to getting "Received and deleted unknown message. Wrong destination?!?"

Tags: python, redis, celery

Iam working with Celery Worker with Redis as broker and in backend.
Steps:

1. Add process will pick the data from queue and process and the result will be send to read queue.
2. Read process will read the data from read queue and print the result.

Before picking up by second task, the message is getting deleted with the below message

[2023-02-02 16:41:29,992: WARNING/MainProcess] Received and deleted unknown message.  Wrong destination?!?

The full contents of the message body was: body: {'task_id': 'e54849dc-3bc7-409c-afab-5c69b3310d99', 'status': 'SUCCESS', 'result': 7, 'traceback': None, 'children': []} (120b)
{content_type:'application/json' content_encoding:'utf-8'
delivery_info:{'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'read'} headers={}}

Code snippet:

```
from kombu import Queue, Exchange
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery('tasks', broker="redis://localhost:6379/0", backend="rpc://")

CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = 'default'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = 'direct'
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = 'default'
celery.conf.update(
    CELERY_ROUTES={
        "celery_worker.celery_worker.add": {
            "queue": "add",
            "routing_key": "add"
        },
        "celery_worker.celery_worker.read": {
            "queue": "read",
            "routing_key": "read"
        }
    },
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue(CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE, Exchange(CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE),
        routing_key=CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY),
Queue("add", Exchange(CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE),
        routing_key="add"),
Queue("read", Exchange(CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE),
        routing_key="read"),
),
CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES = True,
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1)

@celery.task(name='add',acks_late=True)
def add(x, y):
    print(f"Order Complete!{x}, {y}")
    return x + y

@celery.task(name='read',acks_late=True, queue="read", routing_key="read")
def read(data):
    print("data")
    print(f"Order Completedread!{data}")
    return data

task_1 = add.apply_async((4,3), queue='add', routing_key="add", reply_to="read")
```

Help to resolve this issue